# Activation Group and Salience - wrong rule being fired

Tags: drools

I have the following 3 rules in my system.  The facts match all 3 rules.  Based on the salience and activation group I would expect either rule 10 or 11 to fire.  However rule 12 is always firing.

To complicate matters I have 3 systems this runs on. It runs with the expected rule 10 or 11 firing on one system and the other two systems rule 12 is firing.

Any ideas?

```
rule "dimensionConfigMotorTubeDefault_10"
    salience 390
    activation-group "ag_R238_r28-wirefree"
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    when
        p: Product(sku != 1)
        $mm : InventoryChoiceOption(sku == "mm")
        exists (NII(internalPattern in ("R238")) from $mm.value)
        $opt : TextChoiceOption(sku == "motorControl")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("r28-wirefree")) from $opt.value)
        DimensionOption(sku == "dim", widthValue <= "72", heightValue <= "120")
        $edi : TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")
    then
        $edi.setValue("1.5"); update($edi);
end

rule "dimensionConfigMotorTubeDefault_11"
    salience 390
    activation-group "ag_R238_r28-wirefree"
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    when
        p: Product(sku != 1)
        $mm : InventoryChoiceOption(sku == "mm")
        exists (NII(internalPattern in ("R238")) from $mm.value)
        $opt : TextChoiceOption(sku == "motorControl")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("r28-wirefree")) from $opt.value)
        DimensionOption(sku == "dim", widthValue <= "96", heightValue <= "96")
        $edi : TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")
    then
        $edi.setValue("1.5"); update($edi);
end

rule "dimensionConfigMotorTubeDefault_12"
    salience 380
    activation-group "ag_R238_r28-wirefree"
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    when
        p: Product(sku != 1)
        $mm : InventoryChoiceOption(sku == "mm")
        exists (NII(internalPattern in ("R238")) from $mm.value)
        $opt : TextChoiceOption(sku == "motorControl")
        exists (OptionValue(optionValueValue in ("r28-wirefree")) from $opt.value)
        DimensionOption(sku == "dim", widthValue <= "102", heightValue <= "120")
        $edi : TextOption(sku == "default_tube_size")
    then
        $edi.setValue("2"); update($edi);
end
```

Comment: As an aside, I've never before seen `<=` being used with a string comparison, so that seems fishy to me. Can you provide the inputs used that are causing the inconsistent behavior, and identify which version of Drools you're using?

Comment: I am using Drools 5.1.0M2

Yes, I agree that he `<=` with the quotes seems fishy.  I looked into that myself.  I have lots of other rules created via a spreadsheet with both `>` and `<= `and everything in the drl has quotes in it.  I removed the quotes from the rules and got the same results.

I also checked all the facts to make sure everything that should be in there is.
The issue occurs when a different fact is added ini that isn't part of the WHEN clause of these specific rules but there are other rules in the system that use the different fact.

Comment: can you create and share a test which reproduces the issue?

Comment: In addition to what Mike said, the fact that other rules use the additional facts, and you _are_ calling `update`, makes me wonder if you simply have a situation where your data is not what you expect it to be by the time rules 10/11/12 are firing. If you attach a listener to your working memory and log the rules as they hit, that might give you a clue. (You can even put breakpoints in the listener so you can inspect the data as each rule activates, which will help as well.)

Comment: look at the update and the activation groups. the update being made sets a value none of the other rules have a when on that value.  The update is changing a single fact that none of these rules have it the when clause.  again the saliance isn't being observed.  Not the fact that activation-groups are being used.